# Retrieve already signed document with Docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to retrieve a document that has already been signed with docusign API. What I want to do is store like a url to the signed document in the database. So that I can retrieve and render the signed document again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as your account is not configured to purge completed documents (via Document Retention) the DocuSign cloud will have the completed document(s). Please see the REST API documentation:

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Basic%20Scenarios/Retrieving%20Envelope%20and%20Documents.htm?Highlight=documents